# java.io.IOException: Transport scheme not recognised: [amqps]

Tags: java, jmeter, jms, qpid, amazon-mq

I am trying to post a message via JMeter's JMS Publisher Sampler to Amazon MQ (ActiveMQ engine) using `amqps` protocol, but I am receiving a response message:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme not recognised: [amqps].
```

If I use another OpenWire protocol such as `ssl` or `tcp` I am successfully able to post the message. I have also verified that I have the connectivity to the broker from my machine.

I have added Apache Qpid jars and Qpid JMS in classpath.

Is there a way to post messages from JMeter using `amqps` protocol?

Below are the details:

- Initial Context Factory: `org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`
- Provide URL: `amqps://broker-url:5671`
- ConnectionFactory: `ConnectionFactory`
- Destination: `dynamicTopics/topicname`
- Use Authroization is checked.

I am using Qpid JMS 2.5, Geronimo, & ActiveMQ client 5.17.6 jars.

Comment: You need to add more details on your setup, it sounds like your code is using the Openwire client and trying to give it 'amqps' as the protocol which won't work for sure

Comment: Please include the full configuration for your JMeter sampler.

Comment: Below are the details: Initial Context Factory: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory, Provide URL: amqps://broker-url:5671, ConnectionFactory: ConnectionFactory, Destination: dynamicTopics/to=pic name, Use Authroization is checked. I am using qpid jms 2.5, geronimo, activemq client 5.17.6 jars

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using the JNDI initial context factory from the OpenWire JMS client (i.e. `org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`), but you're using a URL scheme (i.e. `amqps`) that's only supported by the Qpid JMS client. This explains why if you use a URL scheme supported by the OpenWire JMS client (i.e. `tcp` or `ssl`) it works.

Since you want to use `amqps` then you need to use the initial context factory from Qpid JMS:

```
org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.JmsInitialContextFactory
```

This is described in the [Qpid JMS 2.5 configuration documentation](https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-2.5.0/docs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your question cannot be comprehensively answered if you don't provide your JMS Publisher Sampler configuration details and [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) (preferably with [JMeter debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for JMS components and the libraries you're using)

Most probably your connection factory is wrong, you need to use [`org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/jms/ActiveMQJMSClient.html) instead of what you're currently using.

Comment: `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` doesn't support the `amqps` URL scheme.